# Converting Nonlinear function to Linear equation

Tags: linear-algebra

How to convert the following nonlinear equation to linear form?

$$y=\frac {x}{2-3x}$$

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange. I'm not sure what you mean.  The way you have defined it, $y$ is not a linear function of $x$

Comment: How to form Y=mX+c equation for the above nonlinear equation?

Comment: you mean like $\frac 1y=2\frac 1x-3 $ ?

Comment: Yes. Any other alternative solution for that?

Comment: For any $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}\backslash\{0\}$, $\frac{\alpha}{y}=\frac{2\alpha}{x}-3\alpha$ for $x,y\neq 0$ is a linear equation in terms of $\frac{\alpha}{x}$ and $\frac{\alpha}{y}$.